# Unable login when creating VM from non-deprovisioned Linux VM image in DevTest Lab

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-devtest-labs

I tried to create a custom image from a VM without doing deprovisioned artifact.  After new VM been created from the custom image.  The VM is unable to login with original password.  Is it a bug?

Here is the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a VM from Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS
2. Create custom image from this VM **without** Run deprovision on virtual machine.
3. Create a new VM from this new image.
4. SSH to this VM with original login/password.  It will failed to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a VM from non-deprovisioned Linux VM image, it will remove the password file from the virtual machine. So you cannot log in the VM.

There are two suggestions for you:

1. Use SSH keys when you are creating the source VM. By using SSH keys
   instead of passwords, the credentials on the machine will persist.
   This way, when a user wants to create a custom image and create new
   VMs from it, he/she can enter the SSH key and access the virtual machine. 
   Hence this should allow you to continue using non-deprovisioned custom images.
2. Run deprovision on the machine while creating a custom image. This
   will allow you to specify credentials which can then be entered while
   creating new virtual machines from the custom image.

For more details, see [Accessing Linux virtual machines created from non-deprovisioned custom images.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devtestlab/2018/03/30/users-are-experiencing-issues-while-trying-to-access-linux-virtual-machines-created-from-non-de-provisioned-custom-images/)